# React animate with CSSTransitionGroup on toggle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I am trying to get a transition between components entering and leaving when the button is clicked to toggle between state

I have also tried putting `<UserDetails />` and `<UserEdit />` as seperate components but have the same result in that no animation is triggered.

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KjIPcMeQF3iriHRqTBW

**Hello.js**

```
import CSSTransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group/CSSTransitionGroup'
import './styles.css'
export default class Hello extends React.Component {
constructor() {
super()

this.state = { showEdit: false }
this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this)
}

handleEdit() { this.setState({ showEdit: !this.state.showEdit }) } 

render() {

 const UserDetails = () => (
 <div className="componenta" key="1">UserDetails</div>
 )
 const UserEdit = () => (
 <div className="componentb" key="2">UserEdit</div>
 )

return(
<div >
    <CSSTransitionGroup 
      transitionName="example"
      transitionEnterTimeout={10}
      transitionLeaveTimeout={600}>
    {this.state.showEdit ? <UserDetails /> : <UserEdit />}
    </CSSTransitionGroup>
    <button onClick={this.handleEdit}>Toggle</button>
</div>
)
}
}
```

**styles.css**

```
.thing-enter {
 opacity: 0.01;
 transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}

.thing-enter.thing-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

 .thing-leave {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
 }

 .thing-leave.thing-leave-active {
  opacity: 0.01;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `key` attribute set to the wrong item - the `<div>` is not the direct descendant of `CSSTransitionGroup` (because your wrapped it into a component by defining it as a function), so it doesn't know which items were added or removed. You have to set your keys to  `UserDetails` and `UserEdit`, so `CSSTransitionGroup` can properly determine changes in it's children.

Here is your `render` method that works:

```
render() {

    const UserDetails = () => (
      <div className="componenta">UserDetails</div>
    )
    const UserEdit = () => (
      <div className="componentb">UserEdit</div>
    )
    return(
    <div >
        <CSSTransitionGroup 
          transitionName="example"
          transitionEnterTimeout={10}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={600}>
        {this.state.showEdit ? <UserDetails key="1" /> : <UserEdit key="2" />}
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
        <button onClick={this.handleEdit}>Toggle</button>
    </div>
    )
  }
```

An alternative would be to store `UserDetails` and `UserEdit` into variables and then render them as such. That will allow you to leave the `key` attributes where they are now, instead of moving them.

Comment: thanks for the explanation makes more sense to me now, How can I prevent both components from displaying at the same time when toggling between them? Currently they appear beneath each other when transitioning but I would like it to fade in/out in the same position on top of each other

Comment: @tomharrison I would solve that with CSS. Either set a delay on the `.thing-enter` transition or set absolute positioning to the elements, so they can be drawn over each other.

Comment: perfect! I have positioned absolutely as I couldn't get delay working as intended the webpack.bin has been updated with working example

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example using display:none to hide the unmounting component

[enter link description here](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KjJ-n0emg6d79whpPF3)